# Изменение цвета пункта ListView

Tags: android, listview

При нажатии на пункт `ListView` меняю цвет пункта

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, longid) {
list.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
```

После того, как вызываю метод

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Цветным становиться другой пункт! 
Как сделать, чтобы нормально менял цвет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SO: Problems with Gallery.getChildAt(int position)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991085/problems-with-gallery-getchildatint-position).

Смысл в том, что position - это не позиция в адаптере, а позиция текущего View относительно первого видимого View в родительском ViewGroup.
Т.е. чтоб работало надо как-то так `list.getChildAt(list.getFirstVisiblePosition()+position)...`

А вообще логичнее работать с id, имхо, хоть может быть и не быстрее...

Comment: Не помогло, getFirstVisiblePosition() всегда 0. Нажимаю на пункт, желтеет(отлично), перехожу на другую активити, возвращаюсь, срабатывает onResume в нем notifyDataSetChanged() и желтеет  противоположный нужному, т.е тот же по счету но с конца! Если закоментить notifyDataSetChanged(), работает!
Делал: view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); проблема отсталась!

Comment: А, была такая проблема. Чекбоксы пытался ставить в своем custom листе. Смысл в том, что view при втором показе activity не пересоздаются, а используются заново и позиции у них искажаются, точнее идут в обратном порядке.  
Правильно все-таки не использовать позицию, а менять значения в адаптере, потом по GetView формировать отображение на основании данных. [Тут][1] помеченный правильным ответ, второй пункт (первый мы уже обсудили:).

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850456/why-does-my-checkedtextview-icon-jump-around-to-different-elements-in-my-gridvie

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!

Answer (score 0):

А по-моему проще менять цвет у адаптера.

Comment: Собсно я так и сделал